# Gradle minify all javascript

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm trying to minify all js files in my app. I was using [gradle-js-plugin](https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin). I was able to minify a single file using that. But I want my all js files to be minified. Here is what i tried. It may seem very dumb in the end, but I'm new to writing something with **Gradle**.

```
plugins {
id "com.eriwen.gradle.js" version "2.12.0"
}

task minifyAll << {

FileTree tree = fileTree('src/main/webapp/resourcesMinified') {
    include '**/*.js'
    exclude '**/*.css'
    exclude '**/*.less'
    exclude '**/*.sass'
}

tree.each { file ->
    def path = file.path

  minifyJs {
   println path
   source = path
   dest = path
   closure {
    warningLevel = 'QUIET'
   }
 }
}
```

Problem is I can not invoke `minifyJs` task from inside `minifyAll`. I tried several things including `execute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** now produces a minimized file for each JS file

I'm using Gradle 2.12 with several JS files in `src/main/webapp/resources`

Given this `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.eriwen.gradle.js" version "2.12.0"
}

import com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask

def srcDir = "src/main/webapp/resources"
def dynamicTaskNames = []
def dynamicTaskIndex = 1

new File(srcDir).eachFile { def file ->
    def dynamicTaskName = "taskMinify${dynamicTaskIndex}"

    task "${dynamicTaskName}"(type: MinifyJsTask) {
        source = file.absolutePath
        dest = "${buildDir}/min.${file.name}"
        closure { warningLevel = 'QUIET' }
    }

    dynamicTaskNames << dynamicTaskName
    dynamicTaskIndex++    
}

task myMinify(dependsOn: dynamicTaskNames) << {
    println ("done.")
}
```

The following works for me:

```
$ gradle myMinify
```

The `myMinify` task has dependencies on several, dynamic tasks which perform the `minifyJs` task for each file. e.g. StringUtils.js will generate `build/min.StringUtils.js`.

I use the ***ICE*** rule when thinking about Gradle: Initialization phase, Configuration phase, Execution phase. In this case, the dynamic tasks are defined during the Configuration phase (i.e. the code that floats freely outside of a task definition). During the Execution phase, `myMinify` calls its dependencies, where the work is performed.

Comment: Thanks Michael. But I want all files to be minified separately. Since my app is not a single page app, minifying all into a single file is not effective for me.

Comment: My mistake ... I will take a look today and update my answer if possible.

Comment: I have changed the answer to produce a minimized file for each file in the original source folder (it should really check the file extension to ensure it is JS, CSS, etc).

Comment: Thank very much Michael, I ll test and accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This might be simpler:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.eriwen.gradle.js' version '2.14.1'
}

import com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask
task minifyJS
minifyJS.doLast {
  fileTree('your files dir').eachWithIndex { file, index ->
    def dynamicTask = "minify$index"
    task "${dynamicTask}" (type: MinifyJsTask) {
      source = file
      dest = file
    }
    tasks."$dynamicTask".execute()
  }
}
```

- Use `eachWithIndex` instead of counter
- Execute dynamic task inside the task

## Alternative answer

You can also use [uglifyjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglifyjs) for this task. (I'm using this way for my scripts because this way is easier than gradle-js-plugin for more complicated situations.)

Prerequisites:

- nodejs
- uglifyjs

```
plugins {
  id 'com.github.jlouns.cpe' version '0.5.0'
}

task minifyJS
minifyJS.doLast {
  fileTree('your files dir').include('**/*.js').eachWithIndex { file, index ->
    def dynamicTask = 'minify' + index
    task "${dynamicTask}" (type: CrossPlatformExec) {
      commandLine uglifyjs, file, '-c', '-m', '-o', file
    }
    tasks."${dynamicTask}".execute()
  }
}
```

- `CrossPlatformExec` helps to execute this task platform independent. If you are using only one platform, you can change it to the `Exec` task type and remove the `plugins` block.
- `-c` option enables compression
- `-m` option enables mangling
- `-o` option specifies output file. This example overwrites the existing file. If you want to change the output file name to .min.js, replace the last `file` at the commandLine to `file - '.js' + '.min.js'`

Comment: thanks, you presented a cleaner style of coding. I think you can add your code to the js plugin of gradle and make this feature available by default.

Comment: thank you. FYI, com.eriwen.gradle.js of v2.14.1 did NOT work under gradle5.4.1, but did work under gradle4.10.3.

Answer (score 2):

Above Michael's answer helped us to solve the issue. We came up with slightly different approach. I thought it would help some one, if I post it.

```
def dynamicTaskNames = []
def dynamicTaskIndex = 1

FileTree tree = fileTree('/home/path/to/app/src/main/webapp/resources') {
   include '**/*.js'
   exclude '**/*.css'
   exclude '**/*.less'
   exclude '**/*.sass'
}

tree.each{file -> def dynamicTaskName = "taskMinify${dynamicTaskIndex}"

    task "${dynamicTaskName}"(type: MinifyJsTask){
        source = file.absolutePath;
        dest = "${buildDir}/min.${file.name}"
        closure.compilationLevel='ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS'
        closure {
            warningLevel = "QUIET"
            compilerOptions.languageIn = "ECMASCRIPT5"
            }
    }

    dynamicTaskNames << dynamicTaskName
    dynamicTaskIndex++
}



task callMinify(dependsOn: dynamicTaskNames) <<{
     println("done.")
}
```

Note : If this doesn't work try adding google closure plugin manually to you script.

Answer (score -1):

The essential part is to create a separate task for every file. That is how this plugin works. Now, you don't know how many files you have, and so you have to write a small code to create as many tasks as the files. Something like :-

```
javascript.source {
 custom {
  js {
   srcDir ""
   include "**/*.js"
   exclude "**/*.min.js"
  }
 }
}


javascript.source.custom.js.files.eachWithIndex {fileSrc, idx ->
def dynName = "jsMinifyTask_${idx}"

task "${dynName}"(type:MinifyJsTask) {

dependsOn createdir

def name = fileSrc.name.replace(".js", "")

source = fileSrc.absolutePath
dest = fileSrc.getParentFile().absolutePath + "/" + name + ".min.js"
closure {
  warningLevel = 'QUIET'
  compilationLevel = 'WHITESPACE_ONLY'
  compilerOptions.languageIn = "ECMASCRIPT5"
  }
 }
}
```

Once you are done with this, write a wrapper task to execute all of these. Something like :-

```
task minify() {
    tasks.findAll {Task task ->
    if(task.name.startsWith("jsMinifyTask_")) {
      task.execute()
      }
    }
}
```

And you are done.

I wrote a Gradle Script to do this on a ThreadPoolExecutor, for faster response. Check it out :-

https://www.concurrenthashmap.com/blog/2017/10/08/gradle-tasks-for-javascript-and-css-minification-and-combination-using-threadpoolexecutor-for-parallel-execution/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17562553)

Comment: MD. Khairul : Apologies. Better now ?