# Gradle minifyJS skip file if failed

Tags: javascript, gradle

I am trying to minify my js in a gradle build following this thread [Gradle minify all javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978782/gradle-minify-all-javascript).  It works as expected, however it fails when it hit's a certain javascript file.  Here is the block of code I am currently using

```
def dynamicTaskNames = []
def dynamicTaskIndex = 1
import com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask

FileTree tree = fileTree("${buildDir}/deploy/scripts/") { 
    include "**/*.js"
    exclude "*.min.js"
}

tree.each{file -> def dynamicTaskName = "taskMinify${dynamicTaskIndex}"
    task "${dynamicTaskName}"(type: MinifyJsTask){
        def name = file.name.replace(".js", "")
        source = file.absolutePath
        dest = file.getParentFile().absolutePath + "/" + name + ".min.js"
        closure {
            warningLevel = "QUIET"
            compilerOptions.languageIn = "ECMASCRIPT5"
        }
        doLast{
            delete file
        }
    }
    dynamicTaskNames << dynamicTaskName
    dynamicTaskIndex++
}

task callMinify(dependsOn: dynamicTaskNames){
    doLast{
        println("done.")
    }
}
```

What I would like it to do is rename the files to .min.js once processed (right now they are just created and then the original js is removed) and the second thing is if it fails to minify, simply skip it.  Here's a sample of the error that halts my build that I would like to avoid

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':taskMinify343'.
> C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:927 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_undef.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:2161 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_undef.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:2184 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_undef.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:2188 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_undef.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:2344 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_undef.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:2344 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_undef.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:2520 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_undef.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:2725 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_eval.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:2735 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_eval.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:5961 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_undef.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:6075 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_undef.
  C:/Users/edunn/Desktop/iC/build/deploy/scripts/diff/dojo/dojo.js:6082 - Ambiguous use of a named function: dj_undef.
```

Thank you in advanced for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I ended up excluding the trouble files and directories from ever been scanned so there is no need to skip any warnings.  Since the failures are happening on 3rd parts JS files I felt comfortable with it instead of re writing the JS.  This is my solution (the relevant part)

```
FileTree tree = fileTree("${buildDir}/deploy/scripts/") { 
    include "**/*.js"
    exclude "*.min.js"
    exclude "**/handsontable/*"
    exclude "**/dojo/*"
}
```